# What is the meaning of the Yellow balls in the second episode of Denki-Gai?

Tags: culture, japanese-language, denkigai-no-honya-san

One of the events of the episode is rolling a huge yellow ball. Hiotan is chosen to represent Umanohone, and there is some gag I did not get by that part.

What is the yellow ball supposed to represent?

Why is Hiotan embarassed and obviously aroused by the balls?

Why Hiotan says she can't be a bride anymore, after being trampled by one of the balls?

Comment: Tha balls are... balls, IYKWIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The balls were meant to be golden. In Japanese, "golden ball" is *kintama*, which is also slang for testicles [according to Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kintama). That's why the girls were so uncomfortable with this metaphor.

Comment: This is not how you answer, this is not how any one answer,follow [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to edit your answer.

Comment: In the future, please don't indent your text; indentation introduces quote blocks and code blocks (for Stack Overflow, Programmers, and other code-using sites), and reading answers in code blocks is rather unpleasant.

Comment: probably a better [reference](https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E9%87%91%E7%8E%89) than Urban, then again who knows if the meaning has been affected by urban

Comment: Well, this is correct though.

Comment: @Memor-X The answer originally just said "Go Google it", so I did, and Urban was actually the only hit within the first five pages that addressed that meaning of the word. The original answer that mirroroftruth's comment responded to was so appallingly bad, I figured anything I could do would improve it. But feel free to edit if you have a better reference.